# Measure-theoretic entropy: Are these partitions equal up to measure zero and does this imply same entropy?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, entropy

Suppose $M\subseteq X$ and we consider the probability spaces $(M,\mathcal{B}(X)_{|M},\mu)$, where $\mathcal{B}(X)$ is the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra of $X$, and $(X,\mathcal{B}(X),\nu)$, where $\nu:=\iota_*(\mu)$ is the pushforward measure of $\mu$ under the embedding $\iota: M\to X$ with $\iota^{-1}(B)=M\cap B$ for $B\in\mathcal{B}(X)$.

Now, let $\alpha=\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k\}$ be any finite, measurable partition of $M$ and $\beta=\{\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_m\}$ any finite measurable partition of $X$.

Isn't it true that, up to sets of measure $\nu=0$,
$$
\alpha = \beta
$$

and in particular that for a continuous map $f\colon X\to X$
the partions
$$
\bigvee_{i=0}^nf^{-i}\beta:=\left\{\bigcap_{i=0}^{n}f^{-i}\beta_{j_i}: j_i\in \{1,\ldots,m\}\right\}
$$
and
$$
\bigvee_{i=0}^{n}(f_{|M})^{-i}\alpha:=\left\{\bigcap_{i=0}^{n}(f_{|M})^{-1}\alpha_{j_i}: j_i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}\right\}
$$
coincide up to sets which have measure $\nu=0$?

(Here with $f_{|M}$ I mean the restriction of $f$ onto $M$ and I suppose that $f(M)\subseteq M$, i.e. $f$ is invariant on $M$.)

I am asking this because if this is true then for the measure-theoretic entropies of $f$ on $(X,\mathcal{B}(X),\nu)$ and of $f_{|M}$ on $(M,\mathcal{B}(X)_{|M},\mu)$, this would imply that these two entropies coincide, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not hypothesized any relation whatsoever between $\alpha$ and $\beta$, so this is not true.

For example let $M=[0,1] \subset [0,2]=X$ and let $\mu$ be Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, so $\nu$ assigns measure zero to $(1,2]$. We could take $\alpha = \{[0,1/2),[1/2,1]\}$ and $\beta = \{[0,3/4],(3/4,2]\}$ for a counterexample.

It should nonetheless be true that those two measure-theoretic entropies of $f$ in your last paragraph do coincide, but not for the reasons you've given. I would suggest instead investigating comparisons between $\bigvee_{i=0}^nf^{-i}\beta$ and $\bigvee_{i=0}^{n}(f_{|M})^{-i}\alpha$ in two special situations:

- when $\beta$ is given and $\alpha = \beta \mid M = \{b \cap M \mid b \in \beta\}$;
- when $\alpha$ is given and $\beta = \alpha \cup \{X-M\}$.

Comment: Let me suggest that for purposes of using this site well, your followup question should be in a new post. Generally speaking, a followup question buried in a comment of an answer to an old post will not be seen by anyone except the answerer, which is not really to your benefit.

Comment: The question in this post was solely about whether certain partitions are the same up to measure zero (they aren't), and whether that implies equality of entropy (a moot point). My added suggestion might be the basis of a new post.